# Issue with giving margin to a jsx element inline

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a jsx element and I am trying to give it a margin style inline. I am having issues with the right syntax to use. i will paste it below

```
<Nunito20 style={{color: frenchGray, margin: 20 0 3 0;}}>Full Name</Nunito20>
```

This gives an error, i also tried with commas and the same issue
pls help

Answer (score 3):

It's a wrong syntax, JS won't understand it.

Use a string instead:

```
<Nunito20 style={{ color: frenchGray, margin: '20px 0 3px 0' }}>Full Name</Nunito20>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in the code. **The style tag in jsx should be a valid javascript object**

So, your code will be converted to:

```
<Nunito20 style={{color: frenchGray, margin: "20px 0 3px 0"}}>Full Name</Nunito20>
```

- the margin value will be one single string
- you need to give **px** to the margin values in this case `"20px 0 3px 0"`. px can be left out if there is only one numeric value such as margin: 20

Comment: Any specific reason to downvote the answer? Everything looks correct to me!

Comment: There's nothing like `frenchGray`

Comment: @kind user. Missed out on my part :-|
I thought frenchGray is some colour and not a variable name so put it in quotes.
I have fixed the solution now.

Answer (score -1):

In JSX, we assign a object for a style. The syntax followed is an invalid javascript object and hence won't work. You must always assign style prop with a valid javascript object.

```
<Nunito20 style={{color: 'frenchGray', margin: "20 0 3 0"}}>Full Name</Nunito20>
```

If the value of a given key in the object, will result in an invalid object, its better to wrap it into quotes.

Comment: The syntax of your answer is also wrong. You can't assign `20 0 3 0` to `margin` property. What you can do is this: `{margin: "20px 0 3px "}`.